# Loading a .html file in django url with parameters

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a file which I have to load directly through the web browser but it would still run inside of my django app.
What I have done so far is

```
url(r"^file_name.html", views.regular_person, name='regular_person')
```

But when I do this it shows the `page could not be found. error 404`

Please how can i get that to work.
Thanks

edit

the file would also have some query parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='filename.html'))
]
```

[django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/)

Is this something you are looking for.

Comment: The path would contain the .html extension. What u gave me does not contain the .html extension. Thanks anyway

Comment: Don't just doing path('foo.html',...) works. I think this works but havenot tested it.

Comment: It works just give the path without r like this:
path('table.html',views.function,name='name')  OR
path ('table.html', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='file.html'))

Comment: @sumit-subebi Thanks I have been able to get it solved, I made a mistake with the view, then later saw my mistake. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad I could help!